# Why sorting a randomly populated array gets progressively faster

Tags: java, sorting, optimization

For a programming exercise, we were told to implement insertion, selection, and bubble sorts (in java).
I wanted to test how fast the sorts executed, so I wrote a loop to randomly populate and sort an array 10 times. The first two sorts take about twice as long as the last 8 iterations.. why?

Here I have put relevant portions of code

```
// class fields
public static final int POPULATE_MAX = 1000000000;
public static final int POPULATE_MIN = -1000000000;

public static void populateRandom(int[] toPopulate)
{
    // populate array with random integers within bounds set by class fields
    for (int i = 0; i < toPopulate.length; i++)
    {
        toPopulate[i] = (int)(Math.random() * (POPULATE_MAX - POPULATE_MIN))
            + POPULATE_MIN;
    }
} // end of method populateRandom(int[] toPopulate)

public static void insertionSort(int[] toSort) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if (toSort == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (toSort.length <= 1) return;

    int temp;

    // Index i points to the next unsorted element; assigned to temp
    for (int i = 1; i < toSort.length; i++)
    {
        temp = toSort[i];

        // This loop searches through the sorted portion of the array and
        // determines where to put the aforementioned unsorted element
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (temp < toSort[j])
            {
                toSort[j + 1] = toSort[j];
                if(j == 0)
                    toSort[j] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                toSort[j + 1] = temp;
                break;
            } // end of if (temp < toSort[j])
        } // end of for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    } // end of for (int i = 1; i < toSort.length; i++)
} // end of method insertionSort(int[] toSort) throws IllegalArgumentException

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long time;
    for (int testRun = 0; testRun < 10; testRun++)
    {
        int[] array = new int[100000];
        System.out.print(testRun + "...");
        populateRandom(array);
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        insertionSort(array);
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i+1]) System.out.println(i + ". Bad");
        }
        System.out.println(time + " Done");
    }
    System.out.println("ABS Done");
}
```

I am guessing that it has to do with branch prediction, but I am not sure as to why subsequent sorts are very noticeably faster.

Comment: Can you post the code that make the test?

Comment: All relevant code is in main(String[])... It creates the arrays and times the sorting

Comment: http://4groundtechsolutions.com/jvm-warmup/

Comment: 1. Branch prediction doesn't work over such long span. 2. Commenting the closing brace is stupid spam. Don't do it and write methods so short that you yourself can see how ridiculous such comments are.

Comment: Sorry... teacher forces us to comment ending braces for everything; docs marks otherwise. I hate commenting so verbosely too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely your JVM is running in interpreted mode for the first couple iterations, then it notices that you are running the same method repeatedly and compiles it to native code. If you call the same method an even greater number of times, it may even cause further optimizations to "kick in".

Because the JVM works this way, you should *always* warm your JVM up before taking performance measurements. Basically, run the code you want to benchmark in a loop a bunch of times, then do the measurements. (Note: this should happen within the space of a single JVM process run -- if the JVM exits and starts up again, you're back to square one.)

Comment: This.  I tend to just run the test harness in an infinite loop, printing the results of each run, and then watch until the results level out.  Each run should still call the test code many times in a loop before reporting the time so that the time measurements have enough precision to be meaningful.  This technique also helps to isolate spikes due to OS process/thread scheduling.